# Mounting Windows server shares in fstab

Tags: server, mount, samba, libreoffice, fstab

I want to be able to save to an XLSM file on Windows Server 2008. I can open the file using LibreOffice but cannot save using smb.

Research has let me to believe that I need to somehow mount the server using cifs instead of smb. I have this line in my fstab file.

```
//192.168.0.16/new_server /media/hpserver cifs -o vers=2.0 iocharset=utf8,credentials=/home/me/.smbcredentials,gid=1000, 0 0
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out what I am missing. I am either getting a parse error with the `-o ver=2.0` or if I remove that part, I get a Host is down error.

Can someone please help me to understand what I am doing wrong? I am running Ubuntu 18.04 64 bits

`/media/hpserver` is an empty existing folder.

Comment: AFAIK the options need to be in a **single** comma-delimited string, like `-o vers=2.0,iocharset=utf8,credentials=/home/me/.smbcredentials,gid=1000` (not sure that a trailing comma is allowed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for posting an answer I can't comment yet. It sounds like a permissions error, I'd look up setting correct permissions for cifs. I had similar issues not being able to write to my shares when I set up my NAS using a raspberry pi. Try something along the lines of `//your/server/ /your/mount/point cifs defaults,uid=username,gid=username,user=user,password=password,rw 0 0` obviously you can replace the username/password bit with you credentials.  Also try `sudo mount -t cifs //your/server /mount/point/ -o username=username` to test mounting without having to reboot.

Comment: I have tried both of your suggestions. The first one I get a parse error --ignored which makes me think I have some wrong syntax somehow, and when connecting from the terminal, I get host is down.

Comment: I've had a look on Google. There's a few suggestions here. https://serverfault.com/questions/414074/mount-cifs-host-is-down

Comment: Making progress here, it did not have the direct answer, however it did link another  source that now has me connecting. I can now mount and access, but no write access. Gonna see if there is a missing command in that line. I am sure the finish line is in sight now. I'll report back.

Comment: I got it!

//192.168.0.16/new_server /media/hpserver cifs defaults,iocharset=utf8,credentials=/home/me/.smbcredentials,gid=1000,vers=1.0,noperm

This is the command I used, and I am now able to connect, and read/write my file! 

Thank you all who helped.

Answer (score 0):

Please install the cifs-utils with:

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
sudo mount -a
```

Comment: I have done this already, I just did it again, and am getting; cifs-utils is already the newest version (2:6.8-1).

Still getting an error when I try and run the mount command.

mount error(112): Host is down

Comment: is telnet 192.168.0.16 139 working??

Comment: Good idea on telnet, however when I try and telnet, it looks like it is frozen for a minute or so, then it passes me a message back "Connection closed by foreign host" It did tell me that the Escape character is '^' which looks like it is working?

What I don't get, is that smb://192.168.... works just fine for accessing, and writing  everything except what I want to write to.